# Decrypt encrypted value outside of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, aes

How can i decrypt a string which has been encrypted using the Laravel 4 Encrypt class, outside of Laravel, only with PHP?

Comment: OpenSSL has a command line interface that might work.

Answer (score 4):

The Laravel `Encrypter` class uses Rijndael with a block size of 256 bit for encryption which is provided by the Mcrypt PHP extension. The `Encrypter` class works using two simple methods, `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`.

An example below:

```
<?php

$secret = Crypter::encrypt('some text here'); //encrypted

$decrypted_secret = Crypter::decrypt($secret); //decrypted

?>
```

**Since you're asking how to do it "outside of Laravel":**

The encryption and decryption is done by the encrypter class. Laravel source is public and here's the relevant part:

```
<?php

    public function encrypt($value)
    {
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->getIvSize(), $this->getRandomizer());
        $value = base64_encode($this->padAndMcrypt($value, $iv));
        $mac = $this->hash($iv = base64_encode($iv), $value);

        return base64_encode(json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac')));
    }

    protected function padAndMcrypt($value, $iv)
    {
        $value = $this->addPadding(serialize($value));
        return mcrypt_encrypt($this->cipher, $this->key, $value, $this->mode, $iv);
    }

    public function decrypt($payload)
    {
        $payload = $this->getJsonPayload($payload);
        $value = base64_decode($payload['value']);
        $iv = base64_decode($payload['iv']);
        return unserialize($this->stripPadding($this->mcryptDecrypt($value, $iv)));
    }

    protected function mcryptDecrypt($value, $iv)
    {
        return mcrypt_decrypt($this->cipher, $this->key, $value, $this->mode, $iv);
    }

?>
```

For documentation and comments, see [Laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php) on GitHub.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `Encrypter` class of Laravel is prone to changes. This is due to some security vulnerabilities that got fixed. So to successfully decrypt you need to do the following things:

1. Get the right source code, e.g. for [4.2.16](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/1f57ba8603453bd6823c0972a3f3f2268fca43b5);
2. Get it to work on your machine. Make sure you run on the same PHP environment (using OpenSSL extensions for the latest versions);
3. Instantiate the class in `Encrypter` with the correct key, and possibly set the correct mode and algorithm;
4. Finally, call `decrypt`.

All other required parameters for decryption (IV and MAC value) should be contained within the ciphertext.