# Decrypt encrypted value outside of Laravel with Php

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

I've read the following questions however, not being familiar with Laravel, I'm still not clear on the most efficient solution and how to code, and 4 years on the current version of Laravel has moved on to 5.6:

[decrypt-encrypted-value-outside-of-laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390898/decrypt-encrypted-value-outside-of-laravel)

[decrypting-outside-laravel](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/decrypting-outside-laravel?page=1) and
[decrypting-outside-laravel-comment](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/decrypting-outside-laravel/replies/384736)

My php script is separate to the CMS that uses Laravel, and it will either be triggered via curl or via cron. The php script fetches a password from the database that has been encrypted by Laravel's encrypt function. The php script will fetch the key (which I believe is base64 encoded) and needs to decrypt the password.

If I instantiate the Encrypter class can the dependancies be minimalised, and will referencing this class work if the script is run from cron? If so what code do I need to instatiate correctly please?

The alternative might be to some how duplicate the encryption code, but then if the Encrypter class code changes then I risk incompatibilities.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Include the relevant portions of code and detail a specific issue that you are having problems with.

Comment: does laravel encrypts passwords in a way you can decrypt it? That seems pretty unsafe! or did you do it yourself? What exactly are you trying to do, verify a password?

Comment: @Luke, it's all in my question above, which part needs further explanation? The code I have so far is not relevant here, I'm just trying to decrypt a value I've fetched from a database field using code compatibly with the Laravel Encrytion class.

Comment: @Kaddath yes with a secret key, please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption

Comment: this could be an XY problem, can you be a bit more precise on what you are trying to do with those passwords, and why you store them, if those explantions don't threat your security? There could be another strategy where you're not obliged to.

Comment: @Kaddath:  I need to store an ftp password that will be transmitted to another system as a login credential.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decrypt the password but you can [verify it against a hash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/hashing).

The optimum way to achieve what you are looking to do would be to create a Command in Laravel and that way you can execute your command via cron and check the plain text password against the hashed password using the Hash::check method.

Comment: This is encryption/decryption, it's not hashing! Please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/encryption

Comment: @NickW The point being made is that you shouldn't encrypt passwords...  You should hash them.

Comment: @Luke I understand that general consensus, but in this instance I need to retrieve the passwords that I previously encrypted. Rather than 'password', let's call it 'data'.

Comment: The only way I could avoid storing a retrievable password in the database would be to use a random password during service setup (eg CMS service) and then allow the user to login to the main system and reset the service password. Resetting the service password to one they enter would then update the service configuration file directly, and then there would be no need to store encrypted passwords in the service manager database. Password vaults like DashLane store encrypted passwords, but their level of encryption will no doubt be much much higher.

Comment: However I think there would almost certainly be an ownership/permissions restriction on editing a config file across hosting account directories.

Comment: @NickW if you can do like you say, it seems much better than to store the password

Comment: Laravel auth scaffolding uses hashing not the encrypt functions for this very reason.  As Luke pointed out this is exactly the point.  You can do this but why one would bypass the built in hashing is beyond me...  Unless you maybe wanted to sneak peak at your users passwords which would be no bueno also!

Comment: @cherrysoft: I think you're focusing on whether I should or should not be encrypting/decrypting passwords rather than what the question was about. I'm sure Laravel uses hashing for passwords, but what does it use for encrypting other data? The passwords will be auto-generated so your aspersions are incorrect. I need to store an ftp password that will be transmitted to another system as a login credential.